# Subversion in Eclipse - Switching branch with uncommitted work in repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

Suppose I have the following senario:

Trunk is my main development line where programmers commit to when done.
Branch V1.0 is a branch I created when releasing version 1.0.

The programmer is working on the trunk but needs to switch to the branch in order to fix bugs.
When switching back to the trunk Subversion will give me the latest in the SVN repository which does not include the recent changes.
So, in order to switch he will have to commit what he has because otherwise the changes are "lost". I know they are still kept in the local repository but it would still mean restoring them one by one once he switchesback.

Am I missing something here?

Edit:

Now I am thinking down these lines:

Each programmer would have his own "private" development branch off of the trunch. He could commit to there whenever he wants. When he has finished what he has written he can them merge it into the trunk. He starts again for the next assignment.
If at any point he is required to fix a bug in some other release he can just commit to his own private branch, fetch the odl release and fix it. Then, after committing the changes to the fix, he can easily switch back to his own development branch.

Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that subversion is not thought for switching as you described. A solution would be to have two workspaces, one for the branch and another one the trunk, so you can switch from one to another without problems. I know it is not a nice one.

Comment: Problem with that is that it means I will have a lot of duplicate stuff on my computer. Can get VERY big over time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to a version control tool that is better suited for your approach. My own suggestion is [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Mercurial), coupled with [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE). The only drawbacks I'm aware of are that Subversion is better suited to store binary files and that Mercurial's subrepositories don't work so well as Subversion's externals.

In Mercurial your programmers would be able to commit their changes to their private repositories, merge and commit locally again, and then push the resulting changes to an official repository, from which other programmers would pull them into their own private repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for such purposes is to have two separate working copies. One for working with trunk and one working with the branch.